# Why we use "Action" in Symfony2 controller's methods?

Tags: php, symfony

I've just started working my way through the symfony2 book.
I wonder why do we named our controller's functions `Action`:

```
public function [something]Action() { // ...
```

In everyone example in the book thus far and all code I see online `Action` is the function name. There's any reason for it?

This works perfectly:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class LuckyController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number/{count}")
     */
    public function countTESTING($count){
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>I DONT HAVE TO CALL THIS somethingACTION</body></html>
        ');
    }

}
?>
```

I've tried googline this but I see no mention or reasoning as to why. Could someone explain why we use that suffix?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's just a conventions. You can use those suffixes, but you can also do without it.

If you have

```
public function somethingAction()
```

in your controller, you can refer it in the routing configuration in this way:

```
index:
    path:      /path_for_something
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Index:something }
```

The `_controller` parameter uses a simple string pattern called the [logical controller name](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#controller-string-syntax). So, `AppBundle:Index:something` means:

- Bundle: *AppBundle*
- Controller class: *IndexController*
- Method name: *somethingAction*

But, you can also do this *without* this feature. Symfony is very flexible, and it does not force you to do almost anything. It is just one of many ways you have to do the same thing.

If you adopt this convention, it's easier for you to understand which `action` do you have in your controller, it's easy for other developer to understand your code, and it's easier for symfony2 to locate your actions/controllers inside your bundle, so that you can also [overriding controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html). This is the best practice.

But if you don't want these benefits, you can using its fully-qualified class name and method as well:

```
index:
    path:      /something
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle\Controller\IndexController::indexAction }
```

But, as the documentation say:

> if you follow some simple conventions, the logical name is more
>   concise and allows more flexibility.

Comment: I know this is a year old but I just had to comment that this is a very concise and complete explanation to the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it wasn't just a naming convention. It was used to execute some code before or after every controller 'action' method. Like checking is user has logged in. 
It is based on magic __call function which is executed for a non-existent or non-public method call.

```
$controller = new Posts();
$controller->index();

class Posts
{
    public function __call($name, $args)
    {
        //run code before    
        call_user_func_array()[$this, "$nameAction"], $args);
        //run code after
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You HAVE TO name your actions

```
public function somethingAction(){}
```

because your routes point to a controller, and the action you want to call.

you can also have private functions in your controller, that you will only name

```
private function something(){}
```

I say that using yml to configure controllers, i dont believe its different when using annotations, but my advise is to use yml for configuring controllers... really !

Comment: Ok i think it get it now, when configuring routes through yml you're actually writing shorthand, soo.. defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Blog:show } actually = "AppBundle:BlogController:showAction". It seems this isnt the case for annotations thought, after a bit more testing it seems annotations will just call the nearest function (below it) when matched. I think i will go down the yml route. It makes perfect sense to keep all routes in one place.

Comment: indeed, I use yml for controllers, but annotations for Entities, for me, it quite makes sense.. flag resolved if you think it is..

Comment: I preferred yaml for a long time. The recently released Best Practices for Symfony suggest Annotations as the most concise, or rather, developer friendly configuration format.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

The biggest issue I've had using yaml vs annotations is that with yaml I'm switching among files for zero gain in usability. Without a good IDE your searching for action names quite often.